# Parsing strange web page - multiple html tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a quite strange page. Here's a simplified version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <form id="x" method="post" action="x">
        <input type="hidden" name="v1" value="v" />
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <input type="hidden" name="v2" value="v" />
            </html>
    </form>
</html>
```

Yes, there's an html tag inside the form.

Is this valid (X)HTML at all? I know this was (at least partially) done using Java Server  Faces.

As to the actual problem:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup(html).find("form")
<form id="x" method="post" action="x">
<input type="hidden" name="v1" value="v" />
</form>
```

BeautifulSoup doesn't like this at all, and just pretends it doesn't exist.

Has anyone gone through something similar?
I guess I *could* parse raw XML, but I'd like to use BeautifulSoup, if possible.

Comment: Do you actually expect or need the nested `<html>` tags? I would have thought the desired behaviour for would be to ignore invalid tags gracefully like BeautifulSoup appears to have done.

Comment: @m.brindley yes, I need v2, since the browsers actually send it in the form. BeautifulSoup's behaviour is indeed graceful in this case, but not very helpful in this particular scenario

Comment: Oops, I misread your BS output. I didn't realise it had discarded the second input element along with the extra `<html>` tags. I seem to recall that there are some strict rules when using `DOCTYPE html` - perhaps if you try using BS with 4.01 Transitional, it will act differently.

Comment: @m.brindley 4.01 makes no difference, unfortunately :(

Comment: Damn, and I thought that might be a really clever way to trick BS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this happen when multiple server sources are combined without checking the output. I don't think there's a scenario in which an `html` tag is ever valid in the middle of a document (other than in an `iframe` tag). The snippet you posted certainly isn't valid (validator.w3.org)

If the rogue tag appears in a predictable location, a string replace is a quick solution so that you can subsequently parse it properly.

> I guess I could parse raw XML

Assuming the document conforms to its XHTML doctype for well-formedness (meaning, it is valid XML even if not valid XHTML), you could:

- parse the document as XML
- modify the markup to something valid (e.g. unwrap the inner elements, or change it to a `div`)
- parse as HTML with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: This particular webpage is updated very frequently, so string replace will probably be too brittle. Passing trimmed xml back into BeautifulSoup is a simple and probably effective idea that had not occurred to me, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this, I ended up coding a dynamic string replacement (as I mentioned in a comment, I can't simply cut on a fixed position)

```
def fix_html_inside_html(html):
    i=html.index("<html")
    while True:
        try:
            i=html.index("<html", i+1)
            i2= html.index(">", i)
            i3= html.index("</html>", i)
            html= html[:i]+html[i2+1:i3]+html[i3+7:]
        except ValueError:
            break
    return html
```

Note this *will* fail if there's a ">" inside a html attribute